# How to make selective asset redefinition in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I want to overwrite a css code of an existing asset, for example “kartik\form\ActiveFormAsset”. If i follow the official guide, i will do this:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'kartik\form\ActiveFormAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,   // do not publish the bundle
                'basePath' => '@webroot',
                'baseUrl' => '@web',
                'css' => [
                    '/custom.css',
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

But it automatically changes a path to a js file which i want to keep up-to-date and don’t do any changes.

So, how to overwrite asset only for css, not for js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need  an asset assignment or you want overwrite the assignmente  you could try using registering scripts in your view  .

```
$this->registerCssFile("@web/css/themes/black-and-white.css", [
  'depends' => [\yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset::class],
   'media' => 'print',
], 'css-print-theme');
```

see yii2 guide and reference for this

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-client-scripts
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view